# Trouble positioning customized thumb at the centre of seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I tried to change the width of seekbar and made it thin. But my thumb is not coming at the centre of seekbar. Thumb is a customised 9 patch image.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>
    <SeekBar 
        android:paddingLeft="60dp" 
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress" 
        android:progress="0" 
        android:layout_height="20dp" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/frequency_slider" 
        android:max="1" 
        android:paddingRight="60dp" 
        android:minWidth="60dp"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_normal_thumb" >
        </SeekBar>



</RelativeLayout>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webkit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post the entire xml layout

Comment: <SeekBar 
android:paddingLeft="60dp" 
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress" 
android:progress="0" 
android:secondaryProgress="0"
android:layout_height="25dp" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/frequency_slider" 
android:max="1" 
android:paddingRight="60dp" 
android:thumb="@drawable/seek_normal_thumb" >
</SeekBar>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it right by defining minHeight and maxHeight of the seekbar

Comment: I only had to set maxHeight. :) As for what to set it to: I just experimented with different dp values until it looked right.

Comment: for me it was android:maxHeight="60dp" . really cool ! thanks

Answer (score 5):

After defining an attribute with big value of maxHeight:

```
android:maxHeight="1000dp"
```

SeekBar will be adjusted to the center

Comment: I guess it's connected to how getMinimumHeight() of Drawable class method works. This is an explanation from Javadoc what it returns: "The minimum height suggested by this Drawable. If this Drawable doesn't have a suggested minimum height, 0 is returned."